# How to use vue component across multiple node projects?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, server-side-rendering, vite, vue-ssr

I'm trying to build a website builder within the drag-and-drop abilities via using Vue3. So, the user will be playing with the canvas and generate a config structure that going to post the backend. Furthermore, the server-side will generate static HTML according to this config.

Eventually, the config will be like the below and it works perfectly. The config only can have HTML tags and attributes currently. Backend uses `h()` [function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#basic-usage) to generate dom tree.

My question is: can I use `.vue` component that will generate on the server side as well? For example, the client-side has a `Container.vue` file that includes some interactions, styles, etc. How can the backend recognize/resolve this vue file?

### UPDATE:

Basically, I want to use the Vue component that exists on the Client side on the backend side to generate HTML strings same as exactly client side. (including styles, interactions etc).

Currently, I'm able to generate HTML string via the below config but want to extend/support Vue component itself.

Note: client and server are completely different projects. Currently, server takes config and runs `createSSRApp`, `renderToString` methods.

Here is the gist of how server would handle the API:

https://gist.github.com/yulafezmesi/162eafcf7f0dcb3cb83fb822568a6126

```
{
  id: "1",
  tagName: "main",
  root: true,
  type: "container",
  properties: {
    class: "h-full",
    style: {
      width: "800px",
      transform: "translateZ(0)",
    },
  },
  children: [
    {
      id: "9",
      type: "image",
      tagName: "figure",
      interactive: true,
      properties: {
        class: "absolute w-28",
        style: {
          translate: "63px 132px",
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#rendering-an-app

From the docs:

```js
// this runs in Node.js on the server.
import { createSSRApp } from 'vue'
// Vue's server-rendering API is exposed under `vue/server-renderer`.
import { renderToString } from 'vue/server-renderer'

const app = createSSRApp({
  data: () => ({ count: 1 }),
  template: `<button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>`
})

renderToString(app).then((html) => {
  console.log(html)
})
```

I guess extract the template from request or by reading the submitted Vue file and use that as the `template` parameter value

Comment: this is exactly what I've done on the server side, however, I want to resolve Vue component that coming from the client side.

Comment: what do you mean by resolve? i was initially thinking the contents of  the Vue from client is sent as a text or uploaded as file that will be read from the server.

Comment: resolving means rendering the component with the ability of interactivity like clicking events etc. basically I can import the same component on the client side without any effort because Vite handles automatically. however, when it comes to the server-side, how can I render this component file?